# Supersu complains about needed update

Tags: rooting, twrp, htc-desire, supersu

I have successfully installed TWRP 3.1.1 on my HTC Desire 510. I have rooted the phone with a modified ROM (so I think). 
But supersu keeps complaining: "Die SU-Binary muss aktualisiert werden. Fortfahren?" (i.e. super-su binary must be updated. continue?)
If I continue, I can choose between "normal" installation and "using TWRP/CWM" for installation. Neither works.

- "Normal installation" yields "SU update unsuccessful" and leaves me a reboot or a link to some tutorials.
- "Installation using <strike>TWRM</strike> TWRP manages to boot directly into <strike>TWRM</strike> TWRP (yeah!), but does not change anything. super-SU comes up with the same message after reboot.
- I also downloaded the last super-SU zip and installed it from <strike>TWRM</strike> TWRP, but with the same outcome.

I have some suspicions.

- the phone might not be rooted properly? I unlocked its bootloader according to the HTC standard process (fastboot and token generation on HTC's website). This at least allowed me to install <strike>TWRM</strike> TWRP and a modified ROM. I checked root access with two different root checkers and they told me, my phone was properly rooted
- supersu is somehow broken?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I corrected it transparently. TWRP makes more sense, doesn't it? I'll look up the supersu version I used later, as I can't look it up now, but I downloaded it last friday, and I think it was supposed to be the latest.

Comment: How do I identify v2.79 version 3? I found "SuperSU-v2.79-201612051815" for download. Is that the right version?

Comment: Ok, downloaded it, installed via TWRP, but the superSU app keeps complanining, that I "must" update the binary. Perhaps I just should ignore that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64234/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-ariser).